# Stream collect to collection with diamonds

Tags: java, stream

How can I collect stream to collection with diamonds?

For example, previously I had code like this for singleton list, but for now I can have more than one element.

```
private static final GrantedAuthority userAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
private static final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> defaultUserAuthorities =
        Collections.singletonList(userAuthority);
```

And I trying to do like this, but stuck with Collectors.

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collect = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(r -> r.getName().name())
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(/*What should be here?*/));
```

How can I collect to this `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.collect(Collectors.toList())` can be used, as a `List` is a `Collection`.

Comment: Damn, I feel stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use a `List<? extends GrantedAuthority>` as `List extends Collection`.

```
List<? extends GrantedAuthority> list = user.getRoles().stream()
                .map(r -> r.getName().name())
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .toList();
```

Note that `Collection` does not have the `get` and `add` methods that are provided by `List`, assuming you want to retrieve and/or set the values.